# Using common class constant name in active model concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I want to have multiple models having a common implementation of currency conversion with a common constant name -- here its PRICE_ATTR

```
module Priceable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def value_for(attr, rate)
    (self.send(attr) / rate).round(2)
  end

  PRICE_ATTR.each do |attribute|
    method_name = "#{attribute}_currency".to_sym
    define_method(method_name) do |rate|
      value_for(attribute, rate)
    end
  end
end

class Design
  PRICE_ATTR = [:discount_price, :price]
  include Priceable
end

class Cart
  PRICE_ATTR = [:snapshot_price]
  include Priceable
end
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `Module#included` is for!

```
module Priceable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def value_for(attr, rate)
    (self.send(attr) / rate).round(2)
  end

  def self.included(othermod)
    othermod::PRICE_ATTR.each do |attribute|
      method_name = "#{attribute}_currency".to_sym
      othermod.send :define_method, method_name do |rate|
        value_for(attribute, rate)
      end
    end
  end
end

class Design
  PRICE_ATTR = [:discount_price, :price]
  include Priceable
end

class Cart
  PRICE_ATTR = [:snapshot_price]
  include Priceable
end
```

It gets run when you include Priceable into another module, which is passed as the parameter othermod. In that module, you can iterate over the including module's PRICE_ATTR array and define methods on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below

```
module Priceable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    class_variable_set(:@@price_attrs , [])
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def has_prizes(attrs)
      class_variable_set(:@@price_attrs, attrs)
    end
  end

  def value_for(attr, rate)
    (self.send(attr) / rate).round(2)
  end

  class_variable_get(:@@price_attrs).each do |attribute|
    method_name = "#{attribute}_currency".to_sym
    define_method(method_name) do |rate|
      value_for(attribute, rate)
    end
  end
end

class Design
  PRICE_ATTR = [:discount_price, :price]
  include Priceable
  has_prizes PRICE_ATTR
end

class Cart
  PRICE_ATTR = [:snapshot_price]
  include Priceable
  has_prizes PRICE_ATTR

end
```

Or you can use cattr_accessor for it instead of class_variable_get and class_variable_get

Comment: This has the same issue that the original does; at the time your `@@price_attrs` iterator is run, it's undefined.

Comment: ohhk my bad, did not tested the code, but accessing constants in library code won't be good idea. You should pass the attributes in parameters and define the methods accordingly.